# Does there exist a question that hovers somewhere between on-topic and meta?

Tags: discussion, questions, per-site-meta

More specifically, does there exist a question (or possible question) on any StackExchange site for which it's not obvious or it's arguable whether or not the question should be on its respective Meta or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

- Meta is for meta-discussion.
- The guidance on all our Q&A sites explicitly disallows meta-discussion.
- A question is either meta-discussion or it is not.
- It cannot be both.

> Meta Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites.

...

> The guidance on all our Q&A sites explicitly disallows
>   meta-discussion, to reduce clutter and noise. There's no chit-chat;
>   just questions and answers.
>
> In order to keep improving our sites, though, we need a space to talk
>   about how the sites themselves work.
>
> So each community has a meta to discuss site-specific issues, and Meta
>   Stack Exchange is for conversations about problems and ideas that
>   affect the whole network.

Source https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour